# Why does my program not stop?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

Can anyone tell me, when I'm hitting y/n - why does my game not stop, it only starts again. I'm calling my `isDone()` method before the run, but it just runs over and over again and again.

```
public class Model {
    int numberToGuess = 29;
    int counter;
    boolean isDone;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    public Model() {
        isDone = false;
        run();
    }

    public void run() {
        welcomeMessage();
        while (true) {
            guessNumber();
        }
    }

    public void welcomeMessage() {
        System.out.println("Welcome to " + '\n' + "***** GUESS THE NUMBER *****");
    }

    public void guessNumber() {
        System.out.println("Please enter number and hit 'Enter'" + '\n');
        if (sc.hasNextInt()) {
            int input = sc.nextInt();
            counter++;
            if (input < numberToGuess) {
                System.out.println('\n' + "Your guess is too low!" + '\n');
            } else if (input > numberToGuess) {
                System.out.println('\n' + "Your guess is too high!" + '\n');
            } else {
                System.out.println("Congratulations, you guessed the number!" + '\n' + "You guessed the number in " + counter + " guess." + '\n');
                isDone();
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Invalid input, please enter a number!" + '\n');
            sc.next();
        }
    }

    public void isDone() {
        System.out.println("Do you wanna play again? Enter y/n");
        if (sc.hasNext()) {
            String input = sc.next();
            if ("y".equals(sc))
                if (input.equals("y")) {
                    isDone = false;
                    guessNumber();
                } else if (input.equals("n")) {
                    isDone = true;
                }
        }
        System.out.println("Invalid input, please enter y/n to continue");
        sc.next();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know what this `if ("y".equals(sc))` means?

Answer (score 8):

You have an infinite loop:

```
 while (true)
```

Theres no condition to terminate the program.

You could use your global `isDone` variable and replace the `true` with:

```
while (!isDone)
{
   guessNumber();
}
```

Comment: Same issue still persist after replacing it with, i had already tried that earlier, i just forgot to edit it back before posting it here :). Any suggestions? @Darren Davis :

``    public void run()
    {
        welcomeMessage();

        while (!isDone)
        {
            guessNumber();
        }
    }``

Comment: @Jakob Since it isn't working for you, you really don't know what `if ("y".equals(sc))` means ... can you explain why you've written that?

Answer (score 3):

isDone() method has logical flaw. I have corrected it.

Step 1: Change `while (true)` to  `while (!isDone)`

Step 2: Corrected "y" condition for input and commented last two lines after making isDone=true, which is causing program to continue even after entering "n"

Modified code:

```
public void isDone() {
        System.out.println("Do you wanna play again? Enter y/n");

        if (sc.hasNext()) {
            String input = sc.next();
            if ("y".equals(input)) {
                isDone = false;
                guessNumber();
            } else if (input.equals("n")) {
                isDone = true;
            }
        }
        //System.out.println("Invalid input, please enter y/n to continue");
        //sc.next();
    }
```

**EDIT:** Explanation of flaw in while condition.

**You are comparing scanner object with "y" instead of input value read from the scanner with "y"**

Comment: Can you add the explanation why `if ("y".equals(sc))` won't work here? I guess OP could need that.

Answer (score 0):

one small change you need to do

```
 public void run() {
    welcomeMessage();
    //while (true) {
      while (!isDone) {
        guessNumber();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Okay, now it's working :). The solution:

public class Model
{

```
int numberToGuess = 29;
int counter;
boolean isDone;

Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

public Model()
{
    isDone = false;
    run();
}

public void run()
{
    welcomeMessage();

    while (!isDone)
    {
        guessNumber();
    }
}

public void welcomeMessage()
{
    System.out.println("Welcome to " + '\n' + "***** GUESS THE NUMBER *****");
}

public void guessNumber()
{

    System.out.println("Please enter number and hit 'Enter'" + '\n');

    if (sc.hasNextInt())
    {
        int input = sc.nextInt();

        counter++;

        if (input < numberToGuess)
        {
            System.out.println('\n' + "Your guess is too low!" + '\n');

        }
        else if (input > numberToGuess)
        {
            System.out.println('\n' + "Your guess is too high!" + '\n');
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Congratulations, you guessed the number!" + '\n' + "You guessed the number in " + counter + " guess." + '\n');
            isDone();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Invalid input, please enter a number!" + '\n');
        sc.next();
    }
}

public void isDone()
{
    System.out.println("Do you wanna play again? Enter y/n");

    if (sc.hasNext())
    {
        String input = sc.next();

        if (input.equals("y"))
        {
          isDone = false;
          counter = 0;
        }

        else if (input.equals("n"))
        {

           isDone = true;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid input");
            isDone();
        }
    }
}
```